# Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor `ExecuteScript()` method throwing an exception when passing page objects as params

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a BDD framework using Selenium 2, C#, SpecFlow, Page Objects and Page Factory to initialize the page objects.

For reporting purpose and exception handling I have overridden the event listeners of Selenium basic actions using `EventFiringWebDriver` class and added report calls in overridden methods.

```
public class WebDriverActionListener : EventFiringWebDriver
{
     protected override void OnElementClicked(WebElementEventArgs e)
     {
        base.OnElementClicked(e);
        const string expectedDescription = "Click on the element";
        var actualDescription = String.Format("Successfully clicked on the element '{0}'", ScenarioContext.Current["element"]);
        Reporter.ReportEvent(expectedDescription, actualDescription, Status.Pass); // Logging the low level reporting
        _driver.Sync();
     }
}
```

Now I am creating object for `WebDriverActionListener` class like below:

```
return new WebDriverActionListener(new FirefoxDriver());
```

I am initializing the page objects using the same driver which is initialized above.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Login1_UserName")]
private IWebElement _userName;

public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
{
  _driver = driver;
  PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this);
  if (!(_userName.Displayed && _loginButton.Displayed))
    throw new InvalidPageObjectException("Login page is not displayed", Status.Fail);
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
 _userName.JsClick(); // Java Script click call method
}
```

I have created a method to click some page objects using javascript(very legacy application). I am getting exception when I try to pass the page object element into `ExecuteScript()` method. As per help provided it should accept `IWebElement' as params.

```
public static void JsClick(this IWebElement element)
{
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

But I am unable to use page objects in 'ExecuteScript()` method.

Comment: can you include an example of your executeScript call?

Comment: what is the exact error/exception you are receiving?  Your code looks to be correct so far.

Comment: Well what's the exception?

Comment: InvalidArgsException on `ExecuteScript` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't have a suitable solution but I have a work around for this.

Element which you want to click using Java script, find them using `FindElement()` method of WebDriver rather than creating a page object (only element you want to click using Java script)

```
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Login1_UserName")).JsClick();
```

This approach should work without any exception.

Comment: let me know if that works.  I haven't used the PageFactory to create page objects yet, but if the above code works, it would be a good reason not to. :)

Comment: @Valli_p Awesome. This is working. I still don't understand why `ExecuteScript' is throwing exception with page objects. This is just a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Read it too fast. If I am not mistaking(without testing as well) the extension method is required to be *static*. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: `JsClick()` is an extension method for `IWebElement` interface. we can use like `_userName.JsClick()`.

Comment: But `ExecuteScript` requires you to provide one parameter. Isn't it?

Comment: actually, he is using an extension method.  So syntax would be:  _username.JsClick();

Extension methods in C#:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @aholt Read it too fast. and thanks for the link. Have you noticed that the extension method needs to be static?

Comment: aha!  You are right, I missed that in his code.  Removing downvote.